# Python 2.7.10 Tkinter 8.5 asksaveasfile inserting "{" "}" around filename

Tags: python, tkinter

Tkinter asksaveasfile is inserting brackets around the filename selected:
e.g.

```
outfile = asksaveasfile(mode='w',defaultextension=".txt",initialdir=bgfileloc,initialfile=["%s-import"%selectedBG,".txt"])
```

outfile will have the format "{outfile}"

How do I prevent this behavior

Answer (score 1):

You aren't asking for a file*name*, you are asking for and getting a file*object*. If you want a filename you need the `asksaveasfilename` function.

Answer (score 1):

`asksaveasfile` returns an open file *object*, not a file *name*.

If you want the name you can either use `asksaveasfilename`, or get the `name` attribute of the file object (eg: `outfile.name`)